# Populate CSS value from the controller

Tags: css, rerender, datatable

I have a data table on my vf page and I want to set the width of td and th. Now this width depends on the number of columns present in the table which are dynamic. So if there are 8 columns the width of each td and th will be 12.5% ~ ( 100.0 / 8.0).

I am calculating this width value in my controller when one of my query method runs. Now I understand the DOM is loaded before and initially the width will not exist so this is what I am doing

```
.mytable tbody td, .mytable thead th {
    <apex:outputPanel id="width">
         width: {!columnWidth}%;
    </apex:outputPanel>
 }

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    initData();
}
</script>

<apex:form>
      <apex:actionFunction name="initData" action="{!initializeData}" reRender="width"/>
     //other code
<apex:form>
```

So ideally upon reRender the outputPanel will reRender with the value of columnWidth. But it does not do that.

Is there any other elegant way to handle this?

PS: I am using dataTable because I am implementing fixed table header using css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it the way you're trying to it. Basically wrap the `style` inside the a `outputPanel` and `reRender` it. But I wouldn't recommend it as it is slow and ideally I believe you shouldn't control the Css like features from the class.

```
<apex:page controller="customController">
    <script>
        setTimeout(function(){
            init();
        },2000);
    </script>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!changeColor}" name="init" reRender="somePanel"/>
    </apex:form>
    <apex:outputPanel id="somePanel">
        <style>
            .mainpanel {
                background-color:{!bgColor};
                height: 200px;
            }
        </style>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="mainpanel">
        Blah Blah Blah
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Class:

```
public class customController {
    public String bgColor{get;set;}

    public customController() {
        bgColor = 'Red';
    }

    public void changeColor() {
        bgColor= 'Blue';
    }
}
```

There may be ways you could do it using CSS alone, but I do not have the full knowledge there. But I would definitely recommend javascript / jQuery to achieve what you're trying to do. So this is something you can do using jQuery.

```
$(function(){
    //get the number of columns
    var numberOfColumns = $("#tableId tr:first td").length;

    //set the width.
    $("#tableId tr td").css({"width":(100/numberOfColumns).toString()+"%"});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you get rid of that outputPanel, move the entire Style tag inside the form, and rerender the form with your actionFunction?

Also, it doesn't look like you're actually rerendering the table, so this should resolve that as well.

Comment: Then why don't I get an upvote or solution marker? :(

Comment: Hahaha, sorry buddy I forgot.

Comment: Apparently I can only mark one as the solution, which is weird.